# is it correct to to call the procfs as the VFS?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

A virtual file system (VFS) or virtual filesystem switch is an abstraction layer on top of a more concrete file system. The purpose of a VFS is to allow client applications to access different types of concrete file systems in a uniform way.

This definition seems to be perfect if we see the actual work of VFS.

But at some places people call the procfs and sysfs also the virtual file system because they ( procfs and sysfs ) do not exist actually and are based on dynamic information collected from different processes.

So is it correct to to call the procfs as the VFS. I do not feel so , if it is correct then we are not keeping VFS definition, VFS is a layer to inter-operate among various file systems. It is not a particular file system in itself.  What do you say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procfs, sysfs, debugfs, etc are not the VFS.
They are proper filesystem implementations, lying 'under' the VFS layer.

It's important to realize that they are *real* filesystems in all respects; it's just that they "live" in RAM. As they don't use a non-volatile storage medium, they are sometimes referred to as 'volatile' filesystems or pseudo-fs.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to mention here what I finally concluded.VFS is Virtual Filesystem **Switch** when used as an abstraction layer because it is helping the filesystem switching on the go. While procfs even we consider it as a filesystem, It will be known as virtual file system not a VFS.